# Formula for nth number of the following sequence:

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I have two number sequences but have failed to find a formula for the *nth* term and, also, the formula for the *sum* of the sequence.

First sequence:

> `1 + 4 + 25 + 676 + 458329 + ... + n`
>
> If the previous term is considered $x$, then, the next number would be: $(x+1)^2$ .

Second sequence:

> `1 + 2 + 6 + 42 + 1806 + 3263442 + ... + n`
>
> If the previous term is considered $x$, then, the next number would be: $x(x+1)$ .

I would be grateful; if someone could help with finding the formulas.

Also, could someone guide me as to the general method of finding the formulas for *sums* and *nth* terms for such sequences? What are such types of *series* called?

Comment: You may state that the first sequence is given by the recurrence relation $[a_1=1,a_{n+1}=(a_n+1)^2]$, and that the second sequence is given by the recurrence relation $[a_1=1,a_{n+1}=(a_n)^2+a_n]$.

Comment: Your sequences are in OEIS. http://oeis.org/A004019.

Comment: @barakmanos I think the OP's question asks for an explicit formula. It seems he already states a recursive one.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A007018

Comment: @barakmanos I appreciate you providing a recursive relation but is there not a formula, like, there are for arithmetic or geometric series?

Comment: @JohnMolokach: I know, I suggested a way for stating those recurrence relations properly within the question.

Comment: You might find section 4.3 of these notes helpful: http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~mlerma/papers/discrete_mathematics-2005.pdf

Comment: In the OEIS notes for the first is the statement "In fact a(n+1) = nearest integer to b^(2^n) - 1 where b = 2.25851845058946539883779624006373187243427469718511465966....  The second is http://oeis.org/A007018 with a(n) = floor(c^(2^n)) where c = A077125 = 1.597910218031873178338070118157...